# Rails dynamic migration with second database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to create a rails application that can create database tables in a **non-primary** DB, given a json schema. The app is intended to act as an interface to manage a secondary database. The dynamically created tables will never be accessed by the app except probably (very rarely) to alter the tables.

Here is my setup

```
config
 |
 |- secondary_db.yml
 |- initializers/secondary_db.rb
```

So now my secondary DB config is available throughout the app.

I have a model called `Topic` which accepts an attribute `topic_schema` of type json. Assume that the schema is shallow with no hierarchy or nesting.

```
topic_schema: {
  "type" => "object",
  "required" => ["a", "b"],
  "properties" => {
    "a" => {"type" => "integer"},
    "b" => {"type" => "string"}
  }
}
```

I have to create a service class called TableCreator that can take this json schema and create a table based on it. So every time I create a new `Topic` with a valid json `topic_schema`, the table gets created automatically. Remember my app is never going to read or write from this table, rarely I may have to alter or delete this table. So I do not need to keep track of these tables in my schema.rb file

I can create a service that can convert json schema to [table migration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html). I want to figure out how can I run the migration to my secondary_db without altering the schema file of my application. Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: This is just just my 2c but the whole purpose of migrations are to alter the rails applications database schema as a developer concern and this is miles away from the use case it was designed for. Instead of trying to shoehorn what you're doing into something which is a really bad fit you should really look at just using `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition` and `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` which are DSL's that generate SQL in your own logic classes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is TableCreator class that achieved what I wanted to do.

```rb
    class TableCreator < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]

      def create
        with_secondary_db_connection do
          create_table :ts_test_table, id: false do |t|
            t.datetime 'time'
            t.string 'value'
          end
        end
      end

      def with_secondary_db_connection
        primary = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(TIMESCALE_CONFIG)
        yield
      ensure
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(primary)
      end

    end
```

Thanks [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) for the suggestion